# Javascript Animation Canvas (Figure Movement)

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I'm new to javascript canvas and am trying to figure a few things out. I was able to create the figure just fine, but the actual movement of it is tricky to me. I was able to seek help here on how to wave, but now I'm wondering on how to do more. For instance, is it possible to get the figure to wave, walk to the right, and then jump up and down?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
context = canvas.getContext("2d"); // get Canvas Context object
let timestamp = Date.now();
let wave = false;


draw();

function draw() {
if(Date.now() < (timestamp+500)) return requestAnimationFrame(draw);

context.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = "black"; // #000000
context.arc(200, 50, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
context.fill(); //fill the circle  

context.beginPath(); 
context.lineWidth = 6;
context.stroke();

//body
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(200, 80);
context.lineTo(200, 180);
context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.stroke();

//arms
context.beginPath();
context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.moveTo(200, 100);
context.lineTo(150, 130);
if(wave) { 
context.moveTo(200, 100);
context.lineTo(250, 130);
wave = false;
}
else {
context.moveTo(200, 100);
context.lineTo(250, 70);
wave = true;
}
context.stroke();

//legs
context.beginPath();
context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.moveTo(200, 180);
context.lineTo(150, 280);
context.moveTo(200, 180);
context.lineTo(250, 280);
context.stroke();
timestamp = Date.now();
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400px" height="400px" >
Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas element
</canvas>
```

Comment: You might not realize, but that's a huge project you jumped on. First you will have to learn how to make animation (even without a computer). This may take time so you understand how should move your sticks in order for the brain sees it as natural movement. Then only would you be able to start thinking how to make it programmatically, and here again, you'll have harsh times: how each part are connected, what should happen to joints, the basics of physics etc. This is absolutely too broad a question for SO. And I would advice you to lower your exigences. Start with spritesheets, way easier.

Comment: I was wondering how extensive it would be.. I do CSS Animation and that seems more simple than this. Thank you for this comment and the sprite sheet example. I will look more into it. @Kaiido

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Rigs and Keyframe animation

The simplest animation is via a method called key-framing.

Each step of an animation is called a frame. For computer games there is typically 60 -30 frames a second (fps)

For each frame you need to draw the character in a new position. At 60fps for 5 seconds that is 300 frames.

You could create functions that draw each of the 300 frames where you have worked out the x,y position of each part, but that is a lot of work.

Key frames are a way of reducing the workload by only creating a few specific key points in the animation and letting the computer workout all the other frames in-between.

### Animation loop

First lets setup the animation loop. This function is called once every frame and we use it to get the animation time, clear the canvas and draw the animation.

```
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);  // request the first frame
var startTime; // we need to have start time to match all the animations to.
var gTime; // We use this as a global time. All animation functions will reference this time
function mainLoop(time){ // time is passed automatically by requestAnimationFrame
    if(startTime === undefined){  // this is the first frame so set as the start time
        startTime = time;
    }
    gTime = time - startTime;
    // clear the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    /* the render code will go here */

    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);  // request the next frame

}
```

### A simple object.

At the most basic we can animate an object via its x,y position.

We create a function that draws the object at a position.

```
function drawHead(x,y){
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.fill(); 
}
```

In the animation loop you can now draw the head

```
drawHead(200,50);
```

But that is not animated,

### Tweening

The next step involves creating key frames and interpolating between them.

Say we have two points `x1,y1` and `x2,y2` and we want to move between them over some time, say `time = 2` seconds.

To find the position at `gTime = 1` second (half way) we get the difference between the two points.

```
var dx = x2 - x1;
var dy = y2 - y1;
```

Now we get the time as a fraction of the total time

```
var fTime = gTime / time; // 1 / 2 = 0.5
```

With the time as a fraction and the difference between the two positions we can multiply the difference in position

```
dx *= fTime;
dy *= fTime;
```

Add that to the start position

```
var x = x1 + dx;    
var y = y1 + dy;
```

And we have the position of the object at time 1 second.

We can compact the code

```
var fTime = gTime / time;
var x = (x2 - x1) * fTime + x1;
var y = (y2 - y1) * fTime + y1;
```

For animations you will have many things you will want to animate so you can create a generic function that will tween between any two numbers given a start time and the current time.

```
// where v1, is start value, t1 is start time, 
//       v2, is end value, t2 is end time, 
// and gTime is the global time

function tweenValue(v1, t1, v2, t2, gTime){
    // to get the fraction of time 
    // first how far from the start time (gTime - t1)
    // divided by the time between t1,t1
    // gives (gTime - t1) / (t2 - t1);  get the fraction of time between t1, t2
    // which we plug directly into the formular
   return  (v2 - v1) * ((gTime - t1) / (t2 - t1)) + x1;
}
```

### Locating keyframes

In an animation you may have many 100's of key frames. You need to have a function that will locate the correct key frames depending on the current time. This is a science in its self as there are a whole variety of ways to optimize the search. For now we will use the most basic search.

We define a set of key frames as follows with the x,y position and the time to be at those positions.

```
headKeys = [
    {x : 200, y : 50, time : 0}, // x,y,time (time is in seconds
    {x : 300, y : 50, time : 1}, 
    {x : 200, y : 50, time : 2}, // last frame will loop back
]
```

Now we want to find which two key frames are needed for the current time. The current time may be outside the key frame time. For this we will loop any keys so if the time is outside the key-frame times we adjust the time to be inside the keys.

```
function findKeys(keys, gTime){
    // first get total time of keys
    var start = keys[0].time;
    var end = keys[keys.length - 1].time;
    var totalTime = end - start;
    var time = gTime - start; // get time relative to the start time
    // loop the time in to the time between the start and end time (we need to make sure negative time works as well
    time = ((time % totalTime) + totalTime) % totalTime;
    // now time is at some value between and including start and less than end

    // Now find the keys
    var index = 0; // index of the keys
    while(index < keys.length){  // could use while(true) but JS will not optimize un-terminated loops so we avoid that
        if(keys[index].time <= time && keys[index+1].time > time){ // are these the two keys?? 
            return index; // return the index of the first key
        }
        index ++;
    }
    return -1; // This will never happen unless you have some bad values in the keys array
}
```

So let put that in action

```js
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);  
    var startTime; 
    var gTime; 
    
    //===============================================================================
    // Animation code
    function findKeys(keys, gTime){
        var start = keys[0].time;
        var end = keys[keys.length - 1].time;
        var totalTime = end - start;
        var time = gTime - start; 
        time = ((time % totalTime) + totalTime) % totalTime;
        var index = 0;
        while(index < keys.length){  
            if(keys[index].time <= time && keys[index+1].time > time){ 
                return index; 
            }
            index ++;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    function tweenValue(v1, t1, v2, t2, gTime){
       return  (v2 - v1) * ((gTime - t1) / (t2 - t1)) + x1;
    }    
    function tweenCoords(key1, key2, gTime, result = {}){
        var totalTime = key2.time - key1.time;
        result.time = ((((gTime - key1.time) / totalTime) % 1) + 1) % 1;        
        result.x = (key2.x - key1.x) * result.time + key1.x;
        result.y = (key2.y - key1.y) * result.time + key1.y;
        return result;
    }
    //===============================================================================
    // Character functions and animation data

    const headKeys = [ // time in seconds, position in pixels
        {x : 200, y : 50, time : 0}, 
        {x : 300, y : 50, time : 1}, 
        {x : 200, y : 50, time : 2}, 
    ];  
    const keyResult = {x : 0, y : 0, time : 0}; // this holds tween results and saves us creating objects each loop
    function drawHead(x,y){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        ctx.fill(); 
    }   

    function drawCharacter(gTime){
        // draw the head
        var keyIndex = findKeys(headKeys, gTime);
        var headPos = tweenCoords(headKeys[keyIndex], headKeys[keyIndex +1], gTime, keyResult);
        drawHead(headPos.x, headPos.y);
    }
        
    
    function mainLoop(time){ 
        if(startTime === undefined){ 
            startTime = time;
        }
        gTime = (time - startTime) / 1000;  // convert time to seconds
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        
        drawCharacter(gTime)
        
        requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);  // request the next frame
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

### Animating joints

So far I have only shown how to animate positions, but for many situations position will not look good. For example the character waving the arm, If you move the hand up and down the arm length will change, getting shorter and then longer.

So rather than tween between positions you can tween between angles. For characters this is how we usually do all key-frames, as Angles.

We pick a point on the body and draw out from it at the correct angle depending on the key frames.

For your character we would start at the hips.

To draw a line along an angle

```
function drawLine(x,y,angle,length){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(x,y);
    ctx.lineTo(x + Math.cos(angle) * length, y + Math.sin(angle) * length);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

The problem becomes a little more difficult because you will want to also rotate everything attached to the line end. There are many ways to do this, for now it will keep it very simple. We compute the end point and use that as the start of the next joint. We also add the angle to the next line so the total angle of the next line is its plus the previous.

### Creating a rig.

A rig is what we call a description of the object being animated. It describes all the parts and how to draw them.

The following is a simple rig of the character

```
const man = {
  parts: {
    body: {
      len: 60,
      ang: -Math.PI / 2,
      parts: {
        arm1: {
          len: 60,
          ang: Math.PI * (9 / 8), // 1/8th is 22.5 deg
        },
        arm2: {
          len: 60,
          ang: Math.PI * (7 / 8), // 1/8th is 22.5 deg
        },
        neck: {
          len: 20,
          ang: 0,
          parts: {
            head: {
              size: 10,
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    leg1: {
      len: 60,
      ang: Math.PI * (5 / 8), // 1/8th is 22.5 deg
    },
    leg2: {
      len: 60,
      ang: Math.PI * (3 / 8), // 1/8th is 22.5 deg
    }
  }
}
```

It is a tree structure with the parts connected as child nodes. Thus to find the head you follow `man.parts.body.parts.neck.parts.head` The angles are relative to the previous node.

To draw the above rig we use a recursive function.

```js
const man = {
  parts: {
    body: {
      len: 60,
      ang: -Math.PI / 2,
      parts: {
        arm1: {
          len: 60,
          ang: Math.PI * (9 / 8), // 1/8th is 22.5 deg
        },
        arm2: {
          len: 60,
          ang: Math.PI * (7 / 8), // 1/8th is 22.5 deg
        },
        neck: {
          len: 20,
          ang: 0,
          parts: {
            head: {
              size: 10,
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    leg1: {
      len: 60,
      ang: Math.PI * (5 / 8), // 1/8th is 22.5 deg
    },
    leg2: {
      len: 60,
      ang: Math.PI * (3 / 8), // 1/8th is 22.5 deg
    }
  }
}


const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const workPos = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}; // to hold working posints and save having to create them every frame

// this function get the end pos of a line at angle and len starting at x,y
function angLine(x, y, ang, len, pos = {}) {
  pos.x = x + Math.cos(ang) * len;
  pos.y = y + Math.sin(ang) * len;
  return pos;
}

// draws a line
function drawLine(x, y, x1, y1) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
  ctx.stroke();
}

// draws a circle
function drawCircle(x, y, size) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fill();
}


// Recursively draws a rig.

function drawRig(x, y, ang, rig) {
  var x1, y1, ang1;
  if (rig.ang !== undefined) { // is this an angled line?
    var end = angLine(x, y, ang + rig.ang, rig.len, workPos);
    drawLine(x, y, end.x, end.y);
    x1 = end.x;
    y1 = end.y;
    ang1 = ang + rig.ang;
  } else if (rig.size) { // is this the head
    drawCircle(x, y, rig.size);
    x1 = x;
    y1 = y;
    ang1 = ang;
  } else {
    // if rig has a position move to that position to draw parts
    x1 = ang.x !== undefined ? ang.x + x : x;
    y1 = ang.y !== undefined ? ang.y + y : y;
    ang1 = ang;

  }
  // are there any parts attached
  if (rig.parts) {
    // For each part attached to this node
    for (const part of Object.values(rig.parts)) {
      drawRig(x1, y1, ang1, part);
    }
  }
}


drawRig(250, 100, 0, man);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

This rig was created by hand, usually rigs are created via animation software. I use custom in house software to create rigs and animations, but there are many out there you can use. Google will help you find them.

### Tweening the rig.

I am running out of room in the answer so will keep it to code.

I have added key-frames to the rig. The `drawRig` function will use the keyframes if found, else just the normal positions `ang` and `len`

The animations are all spread over different lengths so that the combined animation looks more complex than it really is.

See the code for more details.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const workPos = {x: 0, y: 0}; // to hold working posints and save having to create them every frame
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);  
var startTime; 
var gTime; 

//===============================================================================
// Animation code
function findKeys(keys, gTime){
    var start = keys[0].time;
    var end = keys[keys.length - 1].time;
    var totalTime = end - start;
    var time = gTime - start; 
    time = ((time % totalTime) + totalTime) % totalTime;
    var index = 0;
    while(index < keys.length){  
        if(keys[index].time <= time && keys[index+1].time > time){ 
            return index; 
        }
        index ++;
    }
    return -1;
}

function tweenKeys(key1, key2, gTime, result = {}){
    var totalTime = key2.time - key1.time;
    result.time = ((((gTime - key1.time) / totalTime) % 1) + 1) % 1;        
    if (key1.x !== undefined) { result.x = (key2.x - key1.x) * result.time + key1.x }
    if (key1.y !== undefined) { result.y = (key2.y - key1.y) * result.time + key1.y }
    if (key1.ang !== undefined) { result.ang = (key2.ang - key1.ang) * result.time + key1.ang }
    if (key1.len !== undefined) { result.len = (key2.len - key1.len) * result.time + key1.len }
    if (key1.size !== undefined) { result.size = (key2.size - key1.size) * result.time + key1.size }
    return result;
}

const keyResult = {x : 0, y : 0, ang : 0, len : 0, size : 0,time : 0}; // this holds tween results and saves us creating objects each loop

// this function get the end pos of a line at angle and len starting at x,y
function angLine(x, y, ang, len, pos = {}) {
  pos.x = x + Math.cos(ang) * len;
  pos.y = y + Math.sin(ang) * len;
  return pos;
}

// draws a line
function drawLine(x, y, x1, y1) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
  ctx.stroke();
}

// draws a circle
function drawCircle(x, y, size) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fill();
}


// Recursively draws a rig.

function drawRig(x, y, ang, time, rig) {
  var x1, y1, ang1, end, index;
  if (rig.ang !== undefined) { // is this an angled line?
    if(rig.keys){  // are there key frames???
        index = findKeys(rig.keys, time);
        tweenKeys(rig.keys[index], rig.keys[index+1], time, keyResult);
        end = angLine(x, y, ang + keyResult.ang, keyResult.len, workPos);            
        rig.ang = keyResult.ang;
    }else{
        end = angLine(x, y, ang + rig.ang, rig.len, workPos);
    }
    drawLine(x, y, end.x, end.y);
    x1 = end.x;
    y1 = end.y;
    ang1 = ang + rig.ang;
  } else if (rig.size) { // is this the head
    if(rig.keys){  // are there key frames???
        index = findKeys(rig.keys, time);
        tweenKeys(rig.keys[index], rig.keys[index+1], time, keyResult);
        drawCircle(x, y, keyResult.size);         
    }else{
        drawCircle(x, y, rig.size);
    }
    x1 = x;
    y1 = y;
    ang1 = ang;
  } else {
    // if rig has a position move to that position to draw parts
    x1 = ang.x !== undefined ? ang.x + x : x;
    y1 = ang.y !== undefined ? ang.y + y : y;
    ang1 = ang;

  }
  // are there any parts attached
  if (rig.parts) {
    // For each part attached to this node
    for (const part of Object.values(rig.parts)) {
      drawRig(x1, y1, ang1, time,part);
    }
  }
}
    
// The stick man rig with keyframes

const man = {
  parts: {
    body: {
      len: 60,
      ang: -Math.PI / 2,
      keys : [
        {len : 60, ang : -Math.PI * (5 / 8), time : 0},
        {len : 60, ang : -Math.PI * (3 / 8), time : 1.5},
        {len : 60, ang : -Math.PI * (5 / 8), time : 3},
      ],          
      parts: {
        arm1: {
          len: 60,
          ang: Math.PI * (9 / 8), // 1/8th is 22.5 deg
          keys : [
            {len : 60, ang : Math.PI * (10 / 8), time : 0},
            {len : 60, ang : Math.PI * (8 / 8), time : 2},
            {len : 60, ang : Math.PI * (10 / 8), time : 4},
          ],
        },
        foreArm2: {
          len: 30,
          ang: Math.PI * (7 / 8), // 1/8th is 22.5 deg
          keys : [
            {len : 30, ang : Math.PI * (7 / 8), time : 0},
            {len : 30, ang : Math.PI * (4 / 8), time : 1},
            {len : 30, ang : Math.PI * (7 / 8), time : 2},
          ],
          parts : {
            arm : {
              len: 30,
              ang: Math.PI * (7 / 8), // 1/8th is 22.5 deg
              keys : [
                {len : 30, ang : Math.PI * (1 / 8), time : 0},
                {len : 30, ang : -Math.PI * (2 / 8), time : 0.5},
                {len : 30, ang : Math.PI * (1 / 8), time : 1},
              ],
            }
          }
          
        },
        neck: {
          len: 20,
          ang: 0,
          parts: {
            head: {
              size: 10,
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    leg1: {
      len: 60,
      ang: Math.PI * (5 / 8), // 1/8th is 22.5 deg
    },
    leg2: {
      len: 60,
      ang: Math.PI * (3 / 8), // 1/8th is 22.5 deg
      keys : [
        {len : 60, ang : Math.PI * (3 / 8), time : 0},
        {len : 60, ang : Math.PI * (3 / 8), time : 4},
        {len : 60, ang : Math.PI * (1 / 8), time : 4.5},
        {len : 60, ang : Math.PI * (3 / 8), time : 5},
        {len : 60, ang : Math.PI * (3 / 8), time : 8},
      ],      
    }
  }
}


    

function mainLoop(time){ 
    if(startTime === undefined){ 
        startTime = time;
    }
    gTime = (time - startTime) / 1000;  // convert time to seconds
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    
    drawRig(250, 100, 0, gTime, man);
    
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);  // request the next frame
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

### Complex Animations

To create complex animation we can use key-frames to key sets of key frames. For example you may have a walk animation which uses a set of key-frames, But rather than create all the key-frames for all the walk, you create the keys for only one cycle and then use key-frames to define how many times to repeat the walk animation.

#### Ease functions

The tweening in the above is all linear. This does not look natural in most situations. To fix this you use ease functions. They are placed in the tween function.

The following is a `easeInOut` curve is start slow speeds up and then slows back down. You add it to the tween function (taken from above snippet) as follows.

```
const eCurve   = (v, p = 2) =>  v < 0 ? 0 : v > 1 ? 1 : Math.pow(v, p) / (Math.pow(v, p) + Math.pow(1 - v, p));} 
function tweenKeys(key1, key2, gTime, result = {}){
    var totalTime = key2.time - key1.time;
    result.time = ((((gTime - key1.time) / totalTime) % 1) + 1) % 1;  
    result.time = eCurve(result.time); // add the ease in out
    ... rest of function as normal
```

Comment: Pure Genius! Thanks!

Comment: How do change this in such a way that it does not loop? I'm not sure how to stop the loop and where it's looping. The index count only goes from 0 to 1. Please help

Comment: Please check the `cancelAnimationFrame` method